Any $3$-regular graph on $n$ vertices has a cycle of length $\leq 100 \log n$.
How can I prove that any $3$-regular graph on $n$ vertices has a cycle of length $\leq 100 \log n$?
I don't know any theorems on $k$-regular graphs, only strongly regular graphs, and am struggling to see a combinatorial argument where a $\log$ term may appear.

A small hint is that you can expect a logarithm to appear as "the depth of a tree with $n$ vertices which is balanced in some sense". There is more detail here
